# Alfresco with external IDP

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, alfresco

I have web app which uses Keycloak as an IDP. This app uploads files in alfresco and then shows them with Alfresco preview page.

Files are uploaded using Admin user in shared folder, I don't need authorization to manage different roles and permissions.

I want to have SSO between alfresco and my app so that, user can see files without login in alfresco separately.

Can you give any sample, hint or reference how to implement it?